# How do browsers send http and https requests accordingly

Tags: browser, http, https

When we type a web site name without protocol, browsers give the correct web site with it's correct protocol (i.e. http or https)

For example if I type google.com and hit return key, browser gives me the https://google.com

How does browser do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not standardized behaviour, as no RFC document says how a client should behave if the user does not specify the protocol. But probably, in most default configurations, clients try to connect using a unsecure connection (e.g. `http://`) first. They just guess you meant to type `http://` in front of your URL.

In that case, it's not the client that figures out that this site is available over a secure connection (e.g. `https://`), it's the web server that redirects your client's request. So, when typing `google.com` into your browsers' address bar, your browser first connects to `http://google.com`, and the webserver at `google.com` redirects your request to `https://google.com`. That's why you still end up on the `https://` version of google.

You can even try this by manually typing `http://google.com` in your address bar. Google still redirects you over to `https://google.com`. But this is not the default behaviour of most webserver software out there, Google had to manually specify a "HTTPS redirect" in their webservers' configuration.

Still, it's possible, that some clients try a `https://`-connection first, and only connect over `http://` if that fails. That's a more secure behaviour, and although it's probably not the default in most cases, there is e.g. [HSTS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) that allows sites to flag themselves as `https://`, and some Sites may even be pre-flagged in the browser. (As @kicken pointed out, thanks!) Then there are browser plugins (e.g. "HTTPS Everywhere" for Firefox) that implement this procedure. Those plugins come with lists of sites that offer `https://`-secured connections, and when a user enters the URL of such a site with `http://` or with no protocol at the front, the user gets redirected to the `https://` version by the browser, not by the webserver, even if the website administrator didn't set up a HTTPS redirection for his site.

Comment: [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) allows a browser to go straight to https for flagged sites.  Some sites are pre-flagged in browsers by default.

Comment: I’ll add that to my post, thanks :) I meant things like that by saying „it’s possible that clients try https first“, but I’ll make this more explicit, you’re right.

Comment: Worth pointing out that an attacker really could hijack that initial unsecure connection and redirect you somewhere other than the https version of the site, in a public WiFi scenario for example.  If HTTPS is just stopping a read-only attacker from reading your traffic (credit card numbers), the redirect doesn't hurt.  But if HTTPS is all that's saving you from someone injecting a browser exploit into web pages you see or from redirecting you to a clone of the page with a slightly different URL, then that initial unsecured connection means you're screwed.